# Accessing a VirtualBox shared folder before login on a Windows guest

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, shared-folders

Using VirtualBox, I have a Windows 7 guest VM using VirtualBox on a Windows 7 host machine. I can configured a permanent, read-only, automounting shared folder. I can see the shared folder fine, once I have logged into the guest VM.

I would like the a service on the guest OS to be able to access the shared folder *before* a user has logged into the guest OS. Is this possible? It is OK if the access is only possible using the UNC path, without a mapped drive being available.

The documentation is little ambiguous. In the "Guest Additions" chapter it states that "Guest Additions will automatically mount that folder as soon as a user logs into the guest OS". However this is in the context of when the shared folder will be mapped to a network drive, not describing when the UNC path becomes accessible.

I have seen various comments (eg [this one](http://jhshi.me/2016/07/12/mounting-virtualbox-shared-folder-on-boot/index.html) and [here](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=4646)) which point out for a Linux guest it is possible to force it to load the `vboxvfs` module early to enable access to the shared folders. I can't find an equivalent for Windows Guests.

The alternative is to setup a host-only network to share the folder, but this feels unnecessarily complex if it can be avoided.

Background: the purpose of this setup is to test various script used to install applications and configure a windows machine using WPKG. These scripts are run by the guest before the login screen is should. In production the shared folder would normally reside on a network share somewhere.

Comment: This seems easy enough to determine.  Create a shared location within the VM, log out of the user within the guest os, determine if the shared location can still be accessed.  I suspect it will work like any share folder within Windows though.